# vba select website dropdown list and refresh

Tags: html, vba, drop-down-menu

I am trying to select an option from a dropdown list, and the second dropdown list should change accordingly. (e.g. choose FL as a state in the first dropdown list, the second dropdown list will change to all counties in Florida)

Here is the website: https://ric.novoco.com/tenant/rentincome/calculator/z1.jsp

Right now, I can successfully select option in the first dropdown list named "State". But the second dropdown list named "Statistical Area & Name" will not update automatically...

Here is my code

```
'start a new subroutine called LIHTC for Novogradac Rent & Income Limit
Sub lihtc()

Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
Dim btnOption As Object
Dim btnSelect As Object
Dim ElementCol As Object
Dim ElementCol1 As Object

'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
objIE.Visible = True

'navigate IE to this web page (a pretty neat search engine really)
objIE.navigate "https://ric.novoco.com/tenant/rentincome/calculator/z1.jsp"

WaitFor objIE

Set ElementCol = objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("select")

For Each btnSelect In ElementCol
    If btnSelect.Name = "state" Then

    'Within the "Select" element named "Min_Qualification", group all the "Option" element in "ElementCol1"
    Set ElementCol1 = btnSelect.getElementsByTagName("Option")
        For Each btnOption In ElementCol1
                If btnOption.Value = "FL" Then 'Select the option "FL"
                btnOption.Focus
                     btnOption.FireEvent ("onchange")
                btnOption.Selected = True

                End If
        Next btnOption
    End If
Next btnSelect

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


WaitFor objIE


End Sub

'utility Sub: wait for page to load
Sub WaitFor(ie As Object)
While ie.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3) '<<<<<< wait 3 sec

End Sub
```